# Sorting by a dictionary key with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSManagedObjectContext whose model defines five keys: GUID, Parent, Type, Changed, and Content. Inside of Content I am storing NSDictionarys. NSFetchedResultsController allows me to sort by any of the keys defined in my NSManagedObjectModel but what would really be useful to me is the ability to sort by the NSDictionary's keys. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: By the sound of it, `Content` should be an other entity, not NSData attribute

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort with multiple keys?
GUID, Parent, Type, Changed, and Content are entities or attributes from your entity ?

I suppose you have implemented your fetchedResultsController methods and GUID, Parent, Type, Changed, and Content are the attributes of your model.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
   ...
   ...
   ...
   NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"Parent" ascending:YES];
   NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                          initWithKey:@"Type" ascending:YES];
   [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sort,sort2,nil]];
   ...
   ...
return _fetchedResultsController;    
}
```

Comment: GUID, Parent, Type, Changed, and Content are attributes from my entity. The Content attribut holds a NSDictionary. What I want to figure out is how to sort the NSFetchedResultsController by a value contained in that dictionary.